# what is excat functionality of map() in laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, laravel-query-builder

I am fetching data from the database then I am adding one more attribute to that data. for that I am using `map()` in this function in I am using `$qty` variable which has `5` value let say.
Then I am reducing its value in the next iteration but unfortunately, that's not happening

```
    $qty = $request->product_qty;
    $searchProducts->map(function ($product) use ($qty) {
        $qty_taken = $qty - $product->free_qty;
        $product->setAttribute('qty_taken',$qty);
        $qty = $qty - $product->free_qty;
        return $product;
    });
```

I think every time `map()` is supplying value `5` map is not letting the logic reduce its value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `map()` method iterates over the collection and returns a new collection made of the items returned from the closure passed to `map()`.

Since you're not trying to generate a new collection, `map()` is not what you're looking for. You're simply trying to iterate over the collection and perform some action using each item. For this, you would use the `each()` method. Or, you could use a simple `foreach` loop.

The reason your `$qty` variable is not being updated is because, just like function parameters, `use` parameters are passed by value by default. If you'd like the changes to your `$qty` variable to persist through iterations, you'd need to pass it by reference (prefix the variable with an ampersand (&)).

So, to fix your code, there are two options.

To continue using collection methods, switch to `each()` and pass by reference (notice the ampersand):

```
$qty = $request->product_qty;
$searchProducts->each(function ($product) use (&$qty) {
    $qty_taken = $qty - $product->free_qty;
    $product->setAttribute('qty_taken', $qty);
    $qty = $qty - $product->free_qty;
});
```

You could also just use a plain PHP `foreach`, and then you don't have to worry about the scope of your `$qty` variable, since it's all local.

```
$qty = $request->product_qty;
foreach ($searchProducts as $product) {
    $qty_taken = $qty - $product->free_qty;
    $product->setAttribute('qty_taken', $qty);
    $qty = $qty - $product->free_qty;
});
```

Comment: you are right. performance wise what is better? each() or foreach()

Comment: @BilalArshad Theoretically the foreach, so that you're not making a function call for every item in the collection. However, that is a micro optimization that will never actually make a difference. You're talking microseconds over 1000s of iterations. In this case, you would care more about what code is more readable/maintainable to you. I would think the foreach construct would be easier to understand, at all levels of experience.